# Maven: Why does the project try and build parent projects for 3rd party jars?

Tags: maven

The project that I'm on is rather large and has dozens of pom.xml files. What is driving me nuts is that it takes 10+ minutes to package up. In the output as the entire thing builds I see Dozens if not hundreds of

**[WARNING] Failed to build parent project for ...**

For example:

- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:pom
- cch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar

As you can see these are external library items that are used in the application so my question is why the heck is it trying to build and what in our project pom files are making calls to it to do it? How do I get it to stop?

Comment: If you look above this line there should be execution and plugin that outputs this. Could you include it?

Comment: Please show the full log output instead of an excerpt...

Comment: It is all on another system without network connectivity.

Comment: use 'maven dependency:tree' on to trace the inclusion-path to these artifacts. Add -X to your build to get more information on what is happening, and why it's failing. The message is emitted from 'DefaultProjectBuilder', which is part of maven-core